# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This question:

[What type of alarm goes off when mercenaries invade Nya's apartment building?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106400/what-type-of-alarm-goes-off-when-mercenaries-invade-nyas-apartment-building)

The reason was stated that it's a Trivia question, but it's not really.  I don't know the answer to it, but I recall the scene and it lends to both realism and understanding the motivation of the characters.  Can one of the voters explain how this is considered Trivia?

Comment: But is it relevant? In the scene just before you see a character looking at a "danger! electric stuff inside!" box, and then in the next scene you see the lights go out (i.e. he cut the electricity) and then the alarm starts going off, which is possibly related to the electricity getting shut off (although I don't see why an alarm would go off if that happens), or perhaps it is a fire alarm that this character deliberately activated. The precise nature of the alarm is IMHO irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

I almost closed it as "unclear what you're asking" (or however that's called now). If it *wasn't* literally asking for "what type of alarm" it was (which seems utterly irrelevant and isn't shown to be relevant), then I have difficulties understanding what else it is asking instead. Yes yes, I'm usually myself on the forefront of complaining about users bandwaggoning onto wrong close-reasons, but I just went with what I *did* understand from the unclear question, so chiming into the existing close-votes seemed reasonable.

I *could* reopen it and close it as unclear, but that would seem a bit weird. However, if you or anyone else can find a way to clarify what the question is actually asking instead of what type of alarm system it is or if you can point out how that is relevant, that might improve the question to a large degree.